# array of points to equation

Tags: arrays, math, formula

Is it possible to generate a mathematical formula from an array of points. 
The array of points can have as high as a resolution as desired. To illustrate this idea a bit further see the image below:

[image]

Lets say i as a user can draw a line. And from this line i want to get the mathematical formula that can approximately recreate this line. So i would first convert the line to an array of points. So i would end up with these arrays for the green, red and blue line respectively:

```
var greenLine = [Vector2(0.0, 0,0), Vector2(0.12, 0.12),  Vector2(0.25, 0.25), Vector2(0.37, 0.37), Vector2(0.5, 0.5), Vector2(0.62, 0.62), Vector2(0.75, 0.75)];

var redLine = [Vector2(0.0, 0,5), Vector2(0.2, 0.7),  Vector2(0.4, 0.2), Vector2(0.6, 0.7), Vector2(0.8, 0.2)];

var blueLine = [Vector2(0.0, 0.2), Vector2(0.15, 0.3), Vector2(0.22, 0.04), Vector2(0.3, 0.1), Vector2(0.44, 0.13), Vector2(0.6, 0.25), Vector2(0.75, 0.26), Vector2(1, 0.36)];
```

For the red line we could assume it represents a sine wave type of formula, for the green line we can assume it is a kind of linear growth. but the blue line seems random, so is it possible to convert all lines to a formula?

So how would i convert an array of points to a corresponding math formula?

**Note** The lines are just an illustration of the idea, and the arrays also do not represent these lines exactly.

If this is not the right place to ask, would you be so kind to point me where to ask this. And if something is not clear pls let me know so i can clarify!

Comment: This is not possible unless you assume a certain type of function. You might find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting interesting.

Comment: One thing you could always do is a polynomial fit. Maybe you could train a NN to acknowledge different types of functions; this would mean a little bit of work, though.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann the curve fitting is definitly very interesting! So if i am correct the curve fitting does output an formula for a approx line, right?

Comment: This is essentially a regression or curve fitting problem. My advice is to try fitting a number of different kinds of curves and see which one fits best. Just make up a list and structure your code so it just walks through the list and tries each one. Try to arrange it so that you can easily add more kinds of curves to the list. Start with simple functions such as linear, quadratic, cubic, sine/cosine, etc. and go from there. Good luck and have fun, it's a good problem.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for the suggestions! i sure will :)

Answer (score 0):

Having assumed a certain type of function, the formulae offered by Excel for the chosen trend lines:

[image: SO54368088 examples]

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by cardinal spline polynomial, and similar approaches. There is an entire field on subject, here are some wiki topics on subject of Cardinal Splines [Cubic Hermite spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline), or if you need weighted splines [B-Spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline), so you would know what to look for. Since there are a lot of open source code already solving this and similar programming problems, it would be worth checking github or similar for: [polynomials](https://github.com/search?q=polynomials), [splines](https://github.com/search?q=splines). A most common I use when I need to solve something similar is [tinyspline](https://github.com/msteinbeck/tinyspline), or implement it your self from wiki page directly.